# Laravel 5.4 - Saving data from an excel file to DB

Tags: php, excel, laravel-5.4

I am reading an excel file with the help of this [package](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import). This is the function where I read the file:

```
$path = base_path('public/uploads/' .$file->getClientOriginalName());
$rows = Excel::load($path, function($reader) { })->get()->toArray();

foreach($rows as $row) {
  dd($row);
}
```

But, since the excel table doesn't have column headings I can't sort the data by column, which I need in order to save it to DB.
This is how one row looks like in a foreach loop:

```
array:7 [▼
  "amanda_storsenter" => "Amanda Storsenter"
  "apotek_1" => "Ark Bokhandel"
  10 => 10.0
  2547000 => 2547000.0
  18 => 27.0
  16 => 16.0
  20000 => 20000.0
]
```

I need to access the values by their position not by the key, since I don't know how the keys will look like for all the rows. I am not sure how to do that properly, so that I can then for example do this:

```
    $store = Store::create([
      'title' => $row[1],
      'visitors' => $row[6]
    ]);
```

Comment: Could you please try to var_dump the result of ->get()

Comment: Have not worked with it but by reading doc here is a note 

"Note: by default these attributes will be converted to a slug. You can change the default inside the config excel::import.heading. Available options are: true|false|slugged|ascii|numeric|hashed|trans|original

True and slugged will be converted to ASCII as well when excel::import.to_ascii is set to true. You can change the default separator as well inside the config."

Comment: From doc it looks you have to set `numerice` option in config in order to get numerical indexes instead of slug.

Comment: Yes, that was it, thank you very much for your help @MurtazaBhurgri

Comment: Glad it worked :)